# Changing above/below display(short)skip with memoir causes bad boxes in head/foot

Tags: memoir

I'm using memoir with LuaLaTeX, and changing `\abovedisplayskip`, `\belowdisplayskip`, `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip`. This seems to produce bad boxes in the header and footer. I wonder why.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{amsmath}
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{.5\baselineskip}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{.5\baselineskip}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0\baselineskip}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{.5\baselineskip}
}
\makeatother

\overfullrule=1mm

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

> Overfull \hbox (8.88pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
>       []|
>
> Overfull \hbox (8.88pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
>       []|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(It’s very strange that @egreg hasn’t answered this yet, after 4 hours.)

You are forgetting to put a `%` at the end of the lines of the code of your patch, thereby adding four stray spaces.  Try this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{.5\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{.5\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{.5\baselineskip}%
}
\makeatother

\overfullrule=1mm

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

(I have not checked, but in all probability `\normalsize` is used before the page number, or something like that—I’m very lazy tonight!)

Comment: Thank you. It works. I remember this behavior when you mention it. I still find this whole stray spaces problem in LaTeX quite bizarre. Do you know if there is a checklist I can use to find all/most stray spaces like these?